# List of different sized arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, list, julia

I am trying to return an array of different sized arrays in a Julia function.
In the function, the arrays will be initialized and, in a loop, they will have elements, that are other arrays, pushed to end of the array at each iteration. But I am getting the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching push!(::Type{Array{Array{Float64,1},1}}, ::Array{Float64,1})
```

I am initializing an array of arrays:

```
x = Array{Array{Float64,1},1}
```

But when a push! other array, I get the error:

```
push!(x, y)
```

In python I would just append the new arrays to a list and return the list, how can I accomplish it in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement:

```
julia> x = Array{Array{Float64,1},1}
Array{Array{Float64,1},1}
```

assigns to `x` name of the type.

In order to create an instance of this type add `()` after it:

```
julia> x = Array{Array{Float64,1},1}()
0-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}
```

and now you can `push!` to it:

```
julia> push!(x, [2.5, 3.5])
1-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [2.5, 3.5]
```

Note that you could have initiated `x` with an empty vector accepting vectors of `Float64` in the following way:

```
julia> x = Vector{Float64}[]
0-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}
```

We use two features here:

1. `Vector{Float64}` is a shorthand for `Array{Float64, 1}`.
2. If you create an empty vector using `[]` syntax you can prepend a type of its elements in front of it just like I did in the example.